# Extend Default Configuration of vim

Tags: vim, configuration

I've been using the default configuration of vim for a while and want to make a few changes. However, if I edit `~/.vimrc` it seems to overwrite all other configuration settings of `/etc/vimrc` and such, e.g. now there is no syntax highlighting. Here is what vim loads:

```
:scriptnames
/etc/vimrc
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/archlinux.vim
~/.vimrc
/usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/... <there are a few>
```

In other words I want to keep whatever there is configured in vim, but simply make minor adjustments for my shell user.

What do I need to do to somehow weave `~/.vimrc` into the existing configuration or what do I need to put into `~/.vimrc` so it loads the default configuration?

EDIT:
My intended content of `~/.vimrc`:

```
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
```

Comment: In my experience, this is not usually the way it works...

Comment: @Kusalananda Awesome. So how does it work then?

Comment: how did `~/.vimrc` get to be in the middle of the pack?

Comment: @thrig I really don't know.

Comment: What exactly did you put in vimrc? @thrig not unusual, if you have filetype on, it will load files from `$VIMRUNTIME` based on file types, and that will be after vimrc

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can `source` the global Vim configuration file into your local `~/.vimrc`:

```
unlet! skip_defaults_vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim

set mouse-=a
```

See `:help defaults.vim` and `:help defaults.vim-explained` for details.

Comment: Awesome!!! It's a good thing that questions don't die around here... :)

Answer (score 3):

What I found out is that the default config (`default.vim`) is not loaded if you create a `~/.vimrc` file, so what I did was to put the contents of the default config into vimrc and to add the modifications at the end.

I am assuming you have vim8 and are using default configurations (i.e. you don't have a `~/.vimrc` file)

Copy default config to your user vimrc file:

`cp /usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim ~/.vimrc`

Then open your `~/.vimrc` file and add your configs at the end of it.